# How do I bind a strongly typed array in html

Tags: typescript, angular, typescript1.8

I am a angular 2/TS beginner.

I have this schoolyears component:

```
export class SchoolyearsComponent implements OnInit {

    schoolyears: Schoolyear[] = new Array();
    constructor(
        private _router: Router,
        private _schoolyearsService: SchoolyearsService) {
    }

    ngOnInit()
    {
        this._schoolyearsService.getSchoolyears().subscribe(s => {
            this.schoolyears.push(new Schoolyear(s));
        });
    }
}
```

The data I want to show in the UI is coming as json data. I need to wrap that json data in a custom Schoolyear.ts class and then bind it in the UI.

```
export class Schoolyear {

    constructor(obj)
    {
        this.id = obj.id;
        this.name = obj.name;
        this.startDate = new Date(obj.startDate);
        this.endDate = new Date(obj.endDate);
    }

    id: number;
    name: string;
    startDate: Date;
    endDate: Date;
}

<div>
    <div *ngFor="#s of schoolyears">
        <div style="font-weight:bold;">
            <h4>{{s.id}}</h4>
            <h4>{{s.name}}</h4>
            <p>{{ s.startDate}}</p>
            <p>{{ s.endDate}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

None of those 4 properties are displayed in the UI.

How do I correctly wrap the json data and display it in the UI?

I get no errors in the console output.

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like that:

```
this._schoolyearsService.getSchoolyears().map(years => {
  return years.map(year => new Schoolyear(year));
}).subscribe(years => {
  this.schoolyears = years;
});
```

In your case, you provide the whole list as parameter of the `Schoolyear` class.

Comment: Oh really?? I thought the .map function works like the .select with Linq. Ahh... its really late haha I do NOT even use map... I wanted...

Comment: I do not know why you use TWO map calls because it works with one map call:  this._schoolyearsService.getSchoolyears().subscribe(years => {
            this.schoolyears = years.map(y => new Schoolyear(y));
        });

Comment: In your case it's similar. You need this if you want to move the mapping into your service. In this case, the map operator of observable is necessary to adapt the data flow. Otherwise you're right the map method from array is enough ;-)

Comment: The mapping is a template/view concern as the new Schoolyear object is a template/view concern. Therefore I map in the component :-)